# Can an object call on a method in the class it was instanced?

Tags: java, object, methods, class-method

Basically I have an object of a class that I instance in another class. Inside the other classmI have a method which I would like call from inside the object class. Is there any way to do this?

```
public class ObjectClass{
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private Button button;

   public ObjectClass(int x,int y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;      
       button = new Button("");
       button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
           @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
               stuff();
               //I want to access the method in FirstClass here
               
           }});
   }

   public void stuff() {
       //stuff
   }    
}



public class FirstClass{
   private ObjectClass object;
   private boolean change;

   public FirstClass() {
       change = 1;      
       object = new ObjectClass(3,3);
    
   }

   public void method() {
       this.change = 0;
   }    
}
```

This code uses javafx but my question should be applicable without it

Comment: The methods you define here are _instance_ methods.  This means that they are invoked on a _specific instance_ of the class.  To call a method of `FirstClass` in this context, you need an _instance_ of `FirstClass` on which to call the method.  `new FirstClass().method();` is fine for this.  Another option is to make the methods `static`, which means they are not tied to an instance, but instead, (kind'a) tied to the class itself, and can be invoked without an instance.  In that case, `FirstClass.method();` would work (if you made it `static`).

Comment: If an instance of FirstClass was created in another Main class, is there any way to access that particular instance from ObjectClass? @BeUndead

Comment: You can pass it into the constructor that you have there.  `ObjectClass(int x, int y, FirstClass instance) { ... }`, and then use `instance.method();` where you want to call it.  (If you're not calling it _in_ the constructor, you can store it as a field on your `ObjectClass`, and set the value of that field with the `instance` from the constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that; there is no relationship between 'object A' which was instantiated (`new A()`) at some point, and the 'object B', of type 'TypeB' (`B b = new TypeB();`), where TypeB has the `new A()` line in it. Thus, no you can't do what you want, here.

What you can do is pass an instance of e.g. `FirstClass` and expect the creator (the one who ran `new A()`) to supply themselves (`this`) as an arugment to e.g. the constructor of A:

```
class FirstClass {
    A makeNewA() {
        return new A(this);
    }
}

class A {
    private final FirstClass fc;

    public A(FirstClass fc) {
        this.fc = fc;
    }

    public void doSomethingCallingBackToFc() {
        this.fc.method();
    }
}
```

there is of course no guarantee that the instance of FirstClass handed to A's constructor was the same instance.